# Android - create a layout with a hole as in youtube tutorial

Tags: android, material-design

I need to create a layout with a transparent hole in it, very similar to this from the Youtube app tutorial 
[image]
I don't know how to start implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this library [Showcase View](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) It is definitely what you need.

**Here images:**

[image]

[image]